# get POSTed JSON Array in php

Tags: javascript, php

How can I send a `POST` request along with a `JSON` array to `main.php` to return the value of `key_1`? My current method below doesn't work and I can't figure out how to fix this.

`script.js:`

```
var array = {};
array["key_1"] = "obj_1";
array["key_2"] = "obj_2";
array["key_3"] = "obj_3";

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", "main.php");
http.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
http.send(array);
```

`main.php:`

```
<?php
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    echo ($params["key_1"]);
?>
```

`index.html:`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` does not parse the content. You need to pass the value through `json_decode()`.

```
<?php
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    echo ($params["key_1"]);
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting null in return

Comment: In that case, it looks like your implementation of XMLHttpRequest is not quite right. Check the MDN article on its usage for POST requests - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: so is the problem in the `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in that URL

Answer (score 2):

In `main.php`, use this code:

```
<?php
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    echo $params->key_1;
?>
```

When you decode a JSON string, you convert it to an object of stdClass.

If you want to decode JSON and convert it to an array, use code below:

```
<?php
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    echo $params['key_1'];
?>
```