# Posting JSON and parsing it with php://input is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework

I want to create an object by sending a json to my webserver and parsing the information.

My **javascript** looks like this:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

....

constructor(private http: HTTP){}

...

  // combining and sending the information below 
  createMediaObject(): Observable<any> {
    var url = `${ApiServerUrl}/add_mo`;
    url = encodeURI(url);

    var convertedData = {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [Number(this.mediaObjectForm.value.lng).toString(), Number(this.mediaObjectForm.value.lat).toString()]
        },
        properties: {
          icon: this.mediaObjectForm.value.icon.toString(),
          tags: this.mediaObjectForm.value.tags.toString(),
          topic: this.mediaObjectForm.value.topic.toString(),
          title: this.mediaObjectForm.value.name.toString(),
          description: this.mediaObjectForm.value.description.toString(),
          rotation: this.rotation.toString(),
          media: this.mediaObjectForm.value.contents.toString()
        }
      };

    return from(this.http.post(url, convertedData, {})).pipe(map(res => res.data));
  }
```

---

Now I want to parse the informatik in php using the solution from this post [get POSTed JSON Array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896475/get-posted-json-array-in-php):

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

echo json_encode(array("status" => empty($params)));

try {
    // get posted data
    echo $params["type"];
    if (isset($params["properties"]["topic"])) {
        $object->topic = $params["properties"]["topic"];
        echo $object->topic;
    }
```

However:

```
echo json_encode(array("status" => empty($params)));
```

Output: `{"status" : "true"}` -> that means that something went wrong and params is empty

same with

```
echo $object->topic;
```

Output: `null`

---

Is there a problem in the frontend or backend?
Do I need to change something inside of my configs?

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`?

Comment: I get a String, at least not null

Comment: But is it a valid json string? You can validate it at https://jsonlint.com

Comment: Yes it is! Do I need to parse it to a json and decode it?

Comment: I think the https messed up the json and converted it to a string

Comment: The json should be a string, and `json_decode` should decode it. What do you get if you `var_dump($params);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204213/discussion-between-php-n00b-and-aynber).